# how to make two object value into key and value

Tags: javascript

My Result

let a = [ { _id: '2022-04-08' } ]
let b = [ { totalCount: 3 } ]

The result I want to get instead:

NDE { _id: '2022-04-08', count: 3 }

Comment: you'd say `NDE = {[a._id]: b.totalCount}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```js
let a = [ { _id: '2022-04-08' } ] ;
let b = [ { totalCount: 3 } ];

obj = {};
obj[a[0]._id] = b[0].totalCount;
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just use their key and value to define a new object. To merge 2 objects use `...` operator

```js
let a = [ { _id: '2022-04-08' } ];
let b = [ { totalCount: 3 } ];

const result = {[a[0]._id] : b[0].totalCount}
console.log(result)

//merging 2 objects
let obj = {...a[0], ...b[0]}
console.log(obj)

//merging 2 objects with new property name
let obj2 = {...a[0], count: b[0].totalCount}
console.log(obj2)
```

Comment: Sorry to disturb. I updated my question can you please solve it...?

Comment: just updated my answer. Check it out